# How to process credit card in hosted mode via QBMS Java API

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I modified the sample provided [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/030_qbms/0040_get_building/java_api), but it doesn't work for the hosted app. 
Clearly the problem is the connection ticket, which should not be used from my understanding.

The following is the java class:

```
public class MyPayment {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        QbmsConfiguration qbmsConfiguration =new QbmsConfiguration("/qbmsconnector.properties");

        // Create a JAXB-backed QbmsConnector
        QbmsConnector qbmsConnector =new JaxbQbmsConnector(qbmsConfiguration);

        // Build a charge request...
        CreditCardChargeRequest request =new CreditCardChargeRequest();
        request.setCreditCardNumber("4111111111111111");
        request.setNameOnCard("John Doe");
        request.setExpirationMonth(12);
        request.setExpirationYear(2014);
        request.setAmount(130.00);

        // ...define a connection ticket...
        String connectionTicket ="TGT-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

        // ...and make the payment.
        try{
          CreditCardChargeResponse response = qbmsConnector.creditCardCharge(connectionTicket, request);
          System.out.println(response);
        }catch(QbmsOperationException e){
          System.out.println("Payment failed: "+ e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the qbmsconnector.properties

```
qbmsconnector.applicationLogin=loginidxxxxxx
qbmsconnector.applicationId=123456789
qbmsconnector.environment=ptc
qbmsconnector.model=hosted
qbmsconnector.keyStoreLocation=/qbms
qbmsconnector.keyStorePassword=password111
qbmsconnector.certPassword=password111
qbmsconnector.certAlias=alias_abc
```

It throws the following errors:

```
Payment failed: Application agent not found TGT-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
com.intuit.qbmsconnector.response.QbmsResponseStatusException: Application agent not found TGT-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    at com.intuit.qbmsconnector.jaxb.JaxbResponseExtractor.processSignonNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.intuit.qbmsconnector.jaxb.JaxbResponseExtractor.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at com.intuit.qbmsconnector.jaxb.JaxbResponseExtractor.extractCreditCardChargeResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.intuit.qbmsconnector.jaxb.JaxbQbmsConnector.creditCardCharge(Unknown Source)
    at qbo.MyPayment.main(MyPayment.java:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

`Application agent not found TGT-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Generally indicates 1 or 2 things:

- You're not using a valid connection ticket (is that the actual connection ticket you're using, or did you XXX out the connection ticket?)

OR

- You're using a valid connection ticket, but you're using it with the wrong environment. Connection tickets generated in the PTC environment *do not work* with the production environment, and vice versa. Did you generate the connection ticket for PTC, or for production?

Comment: Hi Keith, I don't think connection ticket should be used for hosted mode. Maybe I should create desktop app instead.

Comment: Connection tickets are used for both HOSTED mode and for DESKTOP mode. With that said, a DESKTOP application is considerably easier to set up.

Comment: Hi Keith, when I used this link https://merchantaccount.ptc.quickbooks.com/j/sdkconnection?appid=12345678&appdata=mydata (replace appid with mine) for hosted app, it doesn't give me the connection ticket. It only gives the connection ticket for desktop app.

Comment: HOSTED mode connection tickets are HTTP POSTed to the URL that you specify. What URL did you specify? Are you *positive* that your URL didn't receive any data from Intuit at all?

Comment: https://merchantaccount.ptc.quickbooks.com/j/sdkconnection?appid=12345678&appdata=mydata is the URL I specified, except I replaced the appid with mine. It will give me the connection ticket if the app id belongs to a desktop app.

Comment: Then you specified the wrong URL. For HOSTED mode connections, you're asked to specify several callback URLs. Those callback URLs need to be URLs on YOUR server that store the data you receive from Intuit. HOSTED mode connections *will NOT show you a connection ticket in the browser* - this is *expected* behavior. They HTTP POST you the connection ticket to the URL you specify instead.